# Glib - g_double_hash causes g_hash_table_contains - uncertain behaviour

Tags: hashtable, contains, glib

```
typedef gchar* String;
typedef gboolean Boolean;
struct ddata
{
    int typ;
    union{
        gchar* a;
    };         
};
typedef struct ddata* ddata;
```

An example structure, the instances of which is inserted into the table.

```
Boolean equals_ddata(ddata a, ddata b)
{
    if (a == NULL || b == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nNULL\n");
            return 0;
        }
    if (a->typ == b->typ)
    {
    switch(a->typ)
    {
        case 1:
            {
            if(strcmp(a->a, b->a) == 0)

                return TRUE;
            break;
        }
        default:
            return TRUE;
    }
}
return FALSE;
}
Boolean hm_equals_ddata(gconstpointer a, gconstpointer b) {
    if (((ddata)a) == NULL || ((ddata)b) == NULL) {
        printf("Key for comparison is NULL in hm_equals_ddata");
        return 0;
    }

return equals_ddata((ddata)a, (ddata)b);
}

int main()
{
    ddata obj1 = (ddata)malloc(sizeof(struct ddata));
    ddata obj2 = (ddata)malloc(sizeof(struct ddata));
    ddata obj3 = (ddata)malloc(sizeof(struct ddata));
obj1->typ = 1;
obj1->a = g_strdup("vijay");
obj2->typ = 1;
obj2->a = g_strdup("vijay");
obj3->typ = 2;
obj3->a = g_strdup("kumar");
printf("\n%s, %s, %s\n", obj1->a, obj2->a, obj3->a);
GHashTable* c = g_hash_table_new(g_double_hash, hm_equals_ddata);
printf("%d\n", g_hash_table_insert(c, obj1, NULL));
printf("%d\n", g_hash_table_insert(c, obj2, NULL));
printf("%d\n", g_hash_table_insert(c, obj3, NULL));
printf("%d\n", g_hash_table_contains(c, obj3));
return 0;
}
```

In here the `g_hash_table_contains` is not working properly at times. The equals function attached while creating the hashtable is not called by the
`g_hash_table_contains`, this is due to the `g_double_hash` function. So can anyone explain this undefined behviour.

Answer (score 0):

The hash and equality functions apply to the key in a hash table entry, not to the value. Your code inserts keys of type `ddata` (and values of `NULL`), but then tries to hash them as doubles and compare the keys for equality as `ddata`s.

Try using `g_direct_hash` instead of `g_double_hash`.

Comment: g_direct_hash - I have already tried using this. I get the same problem.

Comment: What makes you think the equals function is not called? Running it under `gdb` and attaching a breakpoint to `equals_ddata`, the breakpoint is hit underneath `g_hash_table_contains()`.